# Give low level functionality to a JMenuItem "Copy" in a GUI that I am creating

Tags: java, swing, jframe, copy, jtextarea

I am creating a low level GUI that has JMenuItems such as copy and paste. I need to create a method selectText() that copies the selected text in a JTextArea that I have incorporated into a JScrollPane. I am trying to figure out the code I should use. I have tried using getSelectedText() but I always get "null" returned. I have some actions that still have no function, or that show a message dialog saying "works" to know that I have added the ActionEvent already, but without any actual functionality. Ultimately, I am trying to add the functionality to the JMenuItem "copy", so I can open a file using the JMenuItem "List Files" (This only opens basic files such as .txt) and then copy the content displayed in the JTextArea by selecting the desired text with the mouse, and then going to Tools > Edit > Copy and using the functionality integrated within that JMenuItem "Copy" to select the text and store it in a string variable with a method called selectText(). Also ignore some of the methods in the class BasicFile since I re-used this from another program that I had to make.

Here is my code:

***MyJFrame.java***

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package MyJFrame;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GraphicsConfiguration;
import java.awt.HeadlessException;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JMenu;
import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
import javax.swing.JMenuItem;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

/**
 *
 * @author Alejandro
 */
public class MyJFrame extends JFrame{

    public MyJFrame(String title) throws HeadlessException {
       super(title);
       super.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.lightGray);
       super.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
       super.setLocation(500,300);
       super.pack();

       //CREATING MENU BAR
       JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
       for(int i = 0; i < Constants.menus.length; i++)
       {
           JMenu newMenu = new JMenu(Constants.menus[i]);
           //CREATING MENU FOR FILE
           if(Constants.menus[i].equals("File"))
           {
               for(int fileItemCounter = 0; fileItemCounter < Constants.fileMenuChoices.length; fileItemCounter++)
               {
                   //ADDING SEPARATOR WHEN NEEDED
                   if(Constants.fileMenuChoices[fileItemCounter].equals("*"))
                   {
                       newMenu.addSeparator();
                   }
                   else if(Constants.fileMenuChoices[fileItemCounter].equals("New"))
                   {
                        JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("New") 
                        {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                            {
                                // Button pressed logic goes here
                                MyJFrame childFrame = new MyJFrame("New File");
                                childFrame.setLocation(600, 400);
                            }
                        });
                        newMenu.add(newMenuItem);
                   }
                   else if(Constants.fileMenuChoices[fileItemCounter].equals("List Files"))
                   {
                       JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("List Files") 
                        {
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                            {
                                // Button pressed logic goes here
                                try
                                {
                                    BasicFile f = new BasicFile();
                                    DisplayText textToBeDisplayed = new DisplayText(f.getName(), f.getContents());
                                    JTextArea text = new JTextArea(textToBeDisplayed.getFileContents(),50, 50);
                                    JScrollPane pane = new JScrollPane(text);
                                    MyJFrame fileOpened = new MyJFrame(textToBeDisplayed.getFileName());
                                    fileOpened.add(pane);
                                    fileOpened.setLocation(600, 400);
                                }
                                catch(FileNotFoundException x)
                                {

                                }        
                            }
                        });
                        newMenu.add(newMenuItem);
                   }
                   else
                   {
                        JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem(Constants.fileMenuChoices[fileItemCounter]);
                        newMenu.add(newMenuItem);
                   }
               }
           }
           //CREATING MENU FOR TOOLS
           if(Constants.menus[i].equals("Tools"))
           {
               for(int toolsItemCounter = 0; toolsItemCounter < Constants.toolsMenuChoices.length; toolsItemCounter++)
               {
                   //CREATING SUBMENU FOR MENU ITEM "EDIT"
                   if(Constants.toolsMenuChoices[toolsItemCounter].equals("Edit"))
                   {
                       JMenu newSubMenu = new JMenu(Constants.toolsMenuChoices[toolsItemCounter]);
                       for(int editMenuChoicesCounter = 0; editMenuChoicesCounter < Constants.editMenuChoices.length; editMenuChoicesCounter++)
                       {
                           if(Constants.editMenuChoices[editMenuChoicesCounter].equals("Copy"))
                           {
                                JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Copy") 
                                {
                                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                                    {
                                        // Button pressed logic goes here
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "works");
                                    }
                                });
                                newSubMenu.add(menuItem);
                           }
                           else if(Constants.editMenuChoices[editMenuChoicesCounter].equals("Paste"))
                           {
                               JMenuItem menuItem = new JMenuItem(new AbstractAction("Paste") 
                                {
                                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                                    {
                                        // Button pressed logic goes here
                                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "works");
                                    }
                                });
                                newSubMenu.add(menuItem);
                           }
                                newMenu.add(newSubMenu);
                       }
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       JMenuItem newMenuItem = new JMenuItem(Constants.toolsMenuChoices[toolsItemCounter]);
                       newMenu.add(newMenuItem);
                   }
               }
           }
           menuBar.add(newMenu);
       }
       super.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
       super.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       MyJFrame mainFrame = new MyJFrame("My First GUI");
    }
}
```

***DisplayText.java***

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package MyJFrame;

import javax.swing.JTextArea;

/**
 *
 * @author Alejandro
 */
public class DisplayText {
    String fileName;
    String fileContents;

    public DisplayText(String fileName, String fileContents) {
        this.fileName = fileName;
        this.fileContents = fileContents;
    }

    public String getFileName() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public String getFileContents() {
        return fileContents;
    }

//    public String selectText()
//    {
//        ;
//    }
}
```

***BasicFile.java***

```
 /*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package MyJFrame;

import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.EOFException;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.io.StreamTokenizer;
import java.util.Scanner;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

/**
 *
 * @author Alejandro
 */
public class BasicFile
{
    File f;
    File backupFile;

    public BasicFile()
    {
                    JFileChooser choose = new JFileChooser(".");
                    int status = choose.showOpenDialog(null);

                    try
                    {
                                    if (status != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
                                            throw new IOException();
                                    f = choose.getSelectedFile();
                                    if (!f.exists()) 
                                            throw new FileNotFoundException();
                    }
                    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
                    {
                                    display(e.toString(), "File not found ....");
                    }
                    catch(IOException e)
                    {
                                    display(e.toString(),  "Approve option was not selected");
                    }
    }

    void display(String msg, String s)
    {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, msg, s, JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }

    // Other methods may be included

    String getContents() throws FileNotFoundException{
     String content = "";
     Scanner readFile = new Scanner(f);
     while(readFile.hasNext()){
         content = content + readFile.nextLine() + "\n";
     }
     return content;
    }

    long getFileSize(){
        return f.length();
    }

    String getPath(){
        return f.getPath();
    }

    String getName(){
        return f.getName();
    }

    String backUpFile(){
        return "File successfully backed up!";
    }

    String displayFileInfo(){
        File parentDirectory = new File(f.getParent());
        File[] filesAndDirectories = parentDirectory.listFiles();
        String filesAndDirectoriesInfo = "";
        for(File f : filesAndDirectories){
            filesAndDirectoriesInfo = filesAndDirectoriesInfo + f.getAbsolutePath() + "\n";
        }
        return "File name: " + f.getName() + "\nAbsolute Path: " + f.getAbsolutePath() + "\nFiles and Directories:\n"
                 + filesAndDirectoriesInfo + "\nFile Size: " + f.length() + " bytes";
    }


   void backupFile() throws FileNotFoundException
   {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Please select or create a file for the backup", "File Backup", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        JFileChooser backupChoose = new JFileChooser(".");
        int backupStatus = backupChoose.showSaveDialog(null);        
        try
        {
                        if (backupStatus != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) 
                                throw new IOException();
                        backupFile = backupChoose.getSelectedFile();
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
                        display(e.toString(),  "Approve option was not selected");
        }
        DataInputStream in = null;
        DataOutputStream out = null;
        try
        {
            in = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(f));
            out = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(backupFile));
            try
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    byte data = in.readByte();
                    out.writeByte(data);
                }
            }
            catch(EOFException e)
            {
                  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File was successfully backed up!",
                                 "Complete", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found",
                                 "Error", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            try
            {
                in.close();
                out.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                display(e.toString(), "Error");
            }
        }
    }

   String countFile()
   {
        try
        {
            int wordCount = 0;
            int numberCount = 0;
            int lineCount = 1;
            int charCount = 0;
            int totalWords = 0;

            FileReader reader = new FileReader(f);
            StreamTokenizer st = new StreamTokenizer(reader);
            st.eolIsSignificant(true);
            st.whitespaceChars(0, ' ');
            st.wordChars('a','z');
            st.wordChars('A','Z');
            do{
                if(st.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_NUMBER){
                    numberCount++;
                    charCount++;
                }
                if(st.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_WORD){
                    charCount += st.sval.length();
                    wordCount++;
                }
                if(st.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_EOL){
                    lineCount++;
                }
                if(st.ttype == StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF){
                    break;
                }
            }while(st.nextToken() != StreamTokenizer.TT_EOF);
            reader.close();
            totalWords = numberCount + wordCount;
            return f.getName() + " has " + lineCount + " lines, " 
                    + totalWords + " words, " + numberCount + " numbers, " + charCount + " characters.  (Approximately)";
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            display(e.toString(), "Error");
        }
        return "null";
   }

   public String findString(String line, String currentLine, String stringToSearch, LineNumberReader lnr) throws Exception  
    { 
      if(currentLine != null)  
      {       
        String s = currentLine.toLowerCase();   

        if(s.contains(stringToSearch.toLowerCase()))  
        {  
           line = line + "\nLine " + lnr.getLineNumber() + ": " + currentLine;  
        }  
        return findString(line, lnr.readLine(), stringToSearch, lnr );
      } 
       return line;
     }  

   String search() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, Exception{
       String stringSearched = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Enter string to search for: ");
       LineNumberReader lnr = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(f));
       String results = findString("", lnr.readLine(), stringSearched, lnr);
       return results;
   }
}
```

***Constants.java***

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package MyJFrame;

/**
 *
 * @author Alejandro
 */
public interface Constants {

    public static final String[] menus = {"File","Tools","Help"};

    public static final String[] fileMenuChoices = {"New", "List Files","*", "Save As", "*", "Close"};

    public static final String[] toolsMenuChoices = {"Sort", "Search", "Edit"};

    public static final String[] editMenuChoices = {"Copy", "Paste"};

}
```

Comment: `JTextArea#getSelectedText` will return `null` *"If the selection is null or the document empty, returns null."* - [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectedText())

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).  An MCVE/SSCCE needs to be ***one*** source file, though that file might contain more than one class.

Answer (score 2):

You should consider using the `JTextArea`s inbuilt functionaliy...

- [`JTextArea#copy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#copy())
- [`JTextArea#cut`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#cut())
- [`JTextArea#paste`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#paste())

You'll probably also want to have a look at [How to Use Actions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html)

Comment: Sorry, I did not explained myself correctly and therefore I also edited the original post. I do understand that I am able to use those inbuilt functionalities, but my goal for this specific project is to basically create a method that is able to use getSelectedText() and store whatever is selected into a String variable; this variable will be later used in another method insertText(int, String) that actually works as the paste inbuilt functionality. I hope I have better explained myself, I am kind of new to java, and it's my first time posting here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: And the point of re-inventing the wheel is?  Do you know you get `ctrl+c`, `ctrl-x` and `ctrl-v` free with these?

Comment: Well I am a computer science student who is basically in his second year; this is an assignment that is probably designed by the professor so the student gets to understand the process that is under the hood of already existing methods and libraries.

Comment: JTextArea#getSelectedText will return null "If the selection is null or the document empty, returns null." - [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#getSelectedText()) - You need to figure out why there is no selected text...

Comment: I understand, and I definitely will try to keep going through the documentation to see if I get the answer. if you do get the chance to run the code I have posted maybe you will better understand what is going on. I open a text file, which displays in the JTextArea, when I go to the edit > copy (while I have already selected some text from the JTextArea) nothing happens, or I get null returned even though I did have something selected, this is what I don't get.